# converting date from string to a required DateTime format in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime

I have a date in string format. I want to convert it to a required DateTime format(mm-dd-yyyy). Here is the code which I am using:

```
from datetime import datetime
demoDate='03-25-17'
requiredDate = datetime.strptime(demoDate, '%m-%d-%y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
print(requiredDate)
print(type(requiredDate))
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
03-25-2017
<class 'str'>
```

May I know if I can get my required output format but in DateTime format not string?

Comment: I mean that I want my date to be stored in DateTime format as mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the call to `strftime`.

```
from datetime import datetime
demoDate='03-25-17'
requiredDate = datetime.strptime(demoDate, '%m-%d-%y') # Note: this line changed, no strftime anymore
print(requiredDate)
print(type(requiredDate))
```

outputs

```
2017-03-25 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

as desired.

You can also output it as a string in mm-dd-yyyy format using the code your originally had:

```
requiredDate = datetime.strptime(demoDate, '%m-%d-%y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

**I think you're confusing the *representation* or *view* and the actual *abstraction* based on your comments.**

**The `datetime` object itself is an *abstraction*.** It represents a date. It doesn't matter if you think about it as `03-25-17` or `2017-03-25`. It is the same date. It also doesn't matter how you beat it into a string (assuming you're using the methods on the class that will keep the semantics of the datetime object). The *abstract* date itself stays the same.

On the other hand, you can beat the `datetime` into a string and then visualize this string in the console using any format the `datetime` class supports. This includes mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy. These are *different representations* of *the same* date. In other words, there are many *representations* or *views* of this date abstraction that we can visualize, but we're only talking about one *abstract* date here.

**Therefore, you can't ask to have a datetime and make sure it's always represented as mm-dd-yyyy. That doesn't make any sense.**

Comment: Put that in the question please. I'll edit in short order.

Comment: @Slickmind I don't think you can do what you're asking. You're confusing the abstraction of a date vs the view of that date.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
requiredDate = datetime.strptime(demoDate, '%m-%d-%y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

You don't need `strftime`:

```
requiredDate = datetime.strptime(demoDate, '%m-%d-%y')
```

Then it will be a good and well `datetime` object